# Array filtering by search query

Tags: javascript

How to filter an array with an particular search term?
for example-- we have an array 
[Tom Harry,Tom John,John Glen,Tom Harward] When we search for  "Tom H" then only Tom Harry and Tom Harward should be come as output
[Tom Harward,Tom Harry];
Using Javascript

```
var k=0;
filter=[];
var fc=input.charAt(0);
var sc=input.charAt(1);
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(array[i].charAt(0)===fc)
    {
        if(array[i].charAt(1)===sc || sc.charAt(1)=="" )
        {       
            filter[k]=[];
            filter[k]=array[i];
            filter[k]=array[i];
            k++;    
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: And have you tried anything? What happened, or went wrong? Where are you stuck? Please at least format your code (currently it's a syntax error, assuming you *meant* to format it as a JavaScript array?), and take a look at the [Mark-down help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it'll help your questions look better, and likely get you more help. Further to your comment: *how did you search*? *Show us your code*.

Comment: I searched for the term only for Tom. But i have to search after the space also not the first word :(

Comment: var k=0;
filter=[];
var fc=input.charAt(0);
var sc=input.charAt(1);
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)

{
 if(array[i].charAt(0)===fc)
 {
 if(array[i].charAt(1)===sc || sc.charAt(1)=="" )
 {
  
  filter[k]=[];
  filter[k]=array[i];
  filter[k]=array[i];
  k++;
 
 }
 else
 {
 continue;
 }

 }
 else
 {
 continue;
 }


}

Comment: Please edit your code into your question, it's practically illegible here in the comments. And, again, please: [read the mark-down help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 8):

If you are working on browsers supporting JavaScript 1.6, [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is your choice. Your problem can be solved by the following one-liner(surely you can generalize it by introducing a function with a `search_pattern` parameter):

```
['Tom Harry','Tom John','John Glen','Tom Harward'].filter(function(name){return name.match(/Tom H/);});
```

If you'd like it also works on old browsers like IE8 or below, it's easy to implement `filter` yourself(The above link contains an implementation). BTW, it's advisable to take use of underscore library which provides many collection manipulation function including [`filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter).

Answer (score 3):

ES6 Implementation, with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/startsWith):

```
['Tom Harry','Tom John','John Glen','Tom Harward'].filter(name => name.startsWith('Tom H'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the search() method inside of a for loop.

### Info on the search() method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Example:

```
for(var i=0; i < nameOfArray.length; i++){
    if(nameOfArray[i].search('Tom H') > -1){
       resultArray.push(nameOfArray[i]); 
    }
}
```

This code will loop through every element in your array and if the text you entered matches partially what you typed (via the search method) it will push the item from the array into a results array. This should create an array that has all matching results.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the String.match() or the String.indexOf() methods.

```
var s="Tom Harry"
 if (s.match(/Tom H.*/)) {
  // do something
}
```

or you can use indexof(),just like

```
s.indexOf("Tom H")
```

and then check the index. If it's >= 0, it contains that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var src1= ["Tom Harry","Tom John","John Glen","Tom Harward"];

alert(searchStringInArray (src1,'Tom H') );


function searchStringInArray (src1,searched) 
{
  var res=""
  for (var j=0; j<src1.length; j++) {
    if (src1[j].match (searched)) 
    {
    res=res+src1[j]+","
    }
}
return res;
} 
</script>
```

use this mate